# Play FrameWork / scala - return a streamed response from an Array[Byte]

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5

I am new to Play and am trying to Stream an Array[Byte] back to the user.  I have been reading the documentation on this at

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaStream

but when I implement this, it says that chunked has been deprecated and that I should use chunked with an Akka streams source instead.  Currently I have

```
Ok.chunked(Source.fromBytes(file))
```

where file is Array[Byte] but the error is:

```
Expected: Source[NotInferredC, _], actual: Source
```

After getting this error I dove deeper trying to get a different solution and then tried to make a Streamed Entity where I have:

```
Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Streamed(Source.fromBytes(file), None, None))
```

and the corresponding error is:

```
expected: Source[ByteString, _] actual: Source
```

I was wondering, how can I convert my Array[Byte] into the appropriate format to be streamed in a response, and also, what are the benefits of choosing the chunked vs sendEntity method.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val file: Array[Byte] = ???
Ok.sendEntity(HttpEntity.Strict(ByteString(file), None))
```

Use `Ok.sendEntity` if your data is small enough for your RAM. But if it's large, then you should store it on your hard drive, taking that by small peaces (chunks) and send them to a user with `Ok.chunked`.